# Add filter to flask+sqlalchemy relationship column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    archived = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.UnicodeText, nullable=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    user = db.relationship(
        'User',
        backref='posts',
        foreign_keys='Post.user_id',
    )
```

How can I add a filter to `Post` on the `user` relationship column to filter out archived users? I want to avoid changing the relationship type to `lazy='dynamic'`, much rather do it in the model here

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property under Post:

```
@property
def unfiltered_posts():
    return SESSION.query(cls).Join(User).filter(User.archived==False).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get the user by `User.query.filter(/**condition/)`
2. then `Post.query.with_parent(user).filter(/**condition/)`

like:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id='')
posts = Post.query.with_parent(user).filter(Post.id > 3).all()
```